# drawRect vs addSubview on UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm customizing the UITableviewCells and I'm trying to figure out which is the most efficient way to do this.

So basically I need to add 3 text strings and 2 images. I could do this by creating UIImageViews and UILabels, but I could also draw it myself by subclassing UITableViewCell. Also I'm concerned about animation on the cells (when going to editMode).

Which is the most efficient way to do this and which one will allow me to do custom animations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are going to *need* to subclass UITableViewCell in any case
2. Add the 3 text strings and 2 images to the UITableViewCell

Now, for the animation of the cells. This raises the same problems/questions as any kind of animation would.

Can you describe some more about what you mean by "Custom Animations" - and what your animating? Are you planning on animating the contents *inside* one of the UIImageViews? If so - maybe a UITimer to fire a needsUpdate on the rect, evoking drawRect in the UIImageView is the way to go.

If you want to do a more standard frame-by-frame type animation from a fixed image (like an animated GIF, for example) - UIImageView will flip between a series of images every [specified] time interval - and can autorepeat.

If you're taking about animating location and rotation, you can just use the standard Animation calls to do that - or via an NSTimer.

So it depends on what level of "Animation" you mean...

Comment: According to Apple's UITableViewCell Class Reference, "You have two ways of extending the standard UITableViewCell object beyond the given styles. To create cells with multiple, variously formatted and sized strings and images for content, you can get the cell's content view (through its contentView (page 12) property) and add subviews to it. You can also subclass UITableViewCell to obtain cell characteristics and behavior specific to your application's needs." That said, I prefer to subclass.

Comment: You can subclass right through XCode, and design/layout the Cell right in Interface Builder - very easy to do!

Comment: I agree. I even voted your answer up 1. But one doesn't "need" to subclass UITableViewCell - even if that is probably the best way to go.

Comment: I just need to change the position of the labels and one of the images, so i guess i'll just do that through the standard animation calls. But i would like to know how your way of doing it performs. I saw this forum thread: http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=188185#post1558789  the guy at post #7 says it's better to draw everything in drawRect, instead of adding subviews. Is this true?

Comment: If you're just doing straight movement - just move the UIView in question. It would be pretty overkill to draw all your own stuff in drawRect. I looked at the article, and don't really understand what he is refering to as "animation". He isn't doing any real "animation" that I can see - aside from view transitions and scrolling - if that is what he is referring to.